# Magento Observer for paypal_prepare_line_items to Adding New Item with paypal and Sub Total Deductions

Tags: magento

I have created a custom module to give the some discount fees for customers. 
I have refereed this [link](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total) to create a custom module for customer fees discounts.

In this case when customer have their own discount points, they will apply the discount points in cart page to reduce the Sub Total and Grand Total. The Changes works fine in cart and checkout page and etc.

My Problem is Order Sub Total and Grand Total not Reflecting in Paypal Payment Gateway Line Items.

So i have wrote the Event Observer to subtract the discount fees with Sub total and Adding new row to paypal line items.

Below code i have tried for adding new line for discount fees and Sub Total deduction

```
<events>
        <paypal_prepare_line_items>
                <observers>
                    <modulename>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>modulename/observer</class>
                        <method>prepareItems</method>
                    </modulename>
                </observers>
         </paypal_prepare_line_items>
</events>
```

And Observer Core is

```
<?php 
class Mycompany_Modulename_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    const TOTAL_FEE = 'Fee';
    const TOTAL_SUBTOTAL = 'subtotal';

    public function prepareItems($observer)
    {   
        $cart = $observer->getPaypalCart();

        if($cart->getSalesEntity()->getFeeAmount())
        {

            $name = 'Custom Discount';
            $qty = '1';
            $amount = -1.00 * $cart->getSalesEntity()->getFeeAmount();
            $identifier = NULL;

            $cart->_shouldRender = true;

            $item = new Varien_Object(array(
                'name'   => $name,
                'qty'    => $qty,
                'amount' => (float)$amount,
            ));

            $cart->_items[] = $item;

            $cart->updateTotal();

        }

        return;

    }

}
```

Can any one point out me right solution?

I need to add discount fees with paypal line items and sub total will be calculated correctly.

Any Help Much Appreciation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you probably have figured it out already.
but you cant do what you are trying, I dont think you can access the _items. instead do:

`$cart->addItem($name, $qty, $amount);`

I dont think that call to the updateTotal is needed, Ive done the previous and the amount was added to the total aggregated amount of the Paypal standard method. I haven't tested on the other methods that uses the API instead of a simple form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the observer class code that should solve your issue:

```
class Mycompany_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function prepareItems(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {        
        $label = SOME_LABEL;
        $qty = SOME_QTY;
        $feeAmount = SOME_FEE_AMOUNT;
        $itemNumber = SOME_IDENTIFIER_OR_SKU;

        /* @var $cart Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart */
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getPaypalCart();

        $cart->addItem($label, $qty, $feeAmount, $itemNumber);

        return $this;
    }
}
```